# RailsIntaller for Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Im an Ubuntu newb, and so far installing programs has been a major PITA for me. Just downloading Sumblime2 text editor in Ubuntu required some terminal commands that im not used to. As opposed on a Mac or Windows simply clicking on the download button. I would like to build some RoR applications in Ubuntu though having to download each bit one by one through the terminal just seems like a huge undertaking. Is there something like Railsinstaller.org that is available for Windows and Mac, for Ubuntu?

Comment: [Maybe you should ask **here**](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but you should really try to learn how to utilize the command line. It may be a pain at the moment but it will help you learn and utilize common practices and tools used for development in Rails (and even other languages).

A great tutorial that helps you through the entire install is something like [this](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/). This should help you get a bit more grasp on the command line "magic" while getting you a clean install. Given the nearly infinite ways that an environment can be setup you will have to decide what tools and methods you choose to install them, which is one reason why one click downloads generally do not exist. They are at best opinionated installations, which is not a bad thing if it falls within your opinion as well but you are only holding yourself back by not learning how to do it for yourself.

Hope this helps!